# MVC Route Segment with a Question Mark?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In [this article](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing) by Sam Saffron, he mentions that Stack Overflow has a route that looks like this:

```
questions/{id}/{title?}
```

Is that a typo?  What does that question mark do?

Comment: IIRC, I think it has something to do with it being optional. I could be wrong though.

Comment: usually, optional parameters are defined like `title = UrlParameter.Optional`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://maproutes.codeplex.com/:

```
[Url("store/{category?}")]
public ActionResult Products(string category)
{
    return View();
}
```

> '?' sign at the end of `{category?}` parameter means that it's
>   optional. `UrlParameter.Optional` will be a default value for it.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow uses [attribute based routing](http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/25/why-i-love-attribute-based-routing/), so I'm guessing that questionmark marks that route parameter as optional.